# passing values from child to parent window

Tags: javascript

I want to pass multiple values in checkoxes from the child window to parent window.

However, I am able to pass single value of single checkbox to parent window.

But when I declare two checkboxes in child window, the parent window shows undefined value

Child Window Code:

```
function post_value(){
   opener.document.cat_tree.catselected.value = document.frm.child_name.value;
   self.close();
}
```

Kindly Advice

Comment: Is your "child window" within an iframe?

Comment: I did not understand your question, please more explanation.

Comment: How are you declaring the two checkboxes? What's the HTML code you're using for them? What changes do you make to your JavaScript code when you have the two checkboxes?

Answer (score 1):

try assigning those multiple checkboxes an ID and doing it this way:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="child_name_1" id="child_name_1" value="value1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="child_name_2" id="child_name_2" value="value2" />

...

function post_value(){
    var all_values = '';
    all_values += document.getElementById('child_name_1').value;
    all_values += ', '+document.getElementById('child_name_2').value;
    opener.document.cat_tree.catselected.value = all_values;
    self.close();
}
```

... it is also possible that you're missing to assign values to your checkboxes in the child window, but I guess that is unlikely since it works with a single one

Comment: yes that's one way.. probably most simple as it requires minimum change in code.

Comment: I need to use many values in checkboxes. So, it can be done only using with same name. Can you suggest JS code to accomplish that.

Comment: Thanks for your concern.  I had solved problem using Java Code and request.getParameterValues();

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script to send username, and a password to the parent window:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            function post_value(){
                var all_values = '';
                all_values += 'id='+document.getElementById('id').value;
                all_values += '&username='+document.getElementById('username').value;
                all_values += '&password='+document.getElementById('password').value;
                window.opener.location='listing.php?'+all_values;
                self.close();
            }
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            body { background-color:#b0c4de; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?=$_GET['id']?>">
            <h2>Log-In</h2>
            <p>Username:</p><input type="text" id="username" name="username">
            <p>Password:</p><input type="text" id="password" name="password">
            <input type="submit" name="login" Value="Log-In" onClick="post_value();" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```